# Setting default value for <select/> using ng-options with (key, value) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set a default value for the following select:

```
<select ng-model="selected"
      ng-options="key as value.Name for (key, value) in attributes">
</select>
```

I use `attributes` as a map with an id as key and an object as value. I want to show the name of the value in the select-box, but bind the key to the model, because when I access `selected`, I need the id, not the name. 
This works but now I want to set a default value. The default value must also show `value.Name`, but bind `id`.

According to [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), it should work something like this:

```
$scope.selected = { 1: {Name : "Attribute1"}};
```

I haven't made it yet. I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

My attributes variable looks like this (TypeScript):

```
export interface IAttributes {
    [id: number]: IAttributeProperties;
}

export interface IAttributeProperties {
    Name: string;
    DataType: string;
}
```

Comment: what does your attributes variable look like?  Are you sure it is using a string '1' instead of 1 as the key?

Comment: I've added the structure of `attributes` to my post. I tried both, with and without string key. Both not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the following default value:

```
$scope.selected = '1';
```

So I just needed to set the `id` (key). In the select box was displayed "Attribute1" now and the related id is bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it with `ng-init` :

```
<select 
      ng-init="selected = attributes[0]" 
      ng-model="selected"
      ng-options="key as value.Name for (key, value) in attributes">
</select>
```

Comment: Thus `attributes` is not an array but an object which I use as a map, this won't work